# How to get Max value from table in Business Objects Web Intelligence

Tags: max, min, business-objects, webi

I'm using Business Objects 4.2 (Web Intelligence)

I have a table with a MAX and MIN Value associated with a Hospital Ward which you can see in the link below:

[Max/Min](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHj1F.jpg)

The Max ward in this instance is **RVH A&E Dept** and the Min is **Ward 1**.

I need to be able to dynamically display the Max and Min wards in the following format but am not quite sure how to go about it:

[Report Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1B9nM.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a simple query on the eFashion universe for my sample data...

[image]

I then created two tables each with just the **State** dimension and aligned them right next to one another. I then ranked one as "Top 1" (shown below) and the other as "Bottom 1".

[image]

To show the labels at the bottom rather than the top I disabled the "Table headers" and enabled the "Table footers" within the **Format Table...** properties. I also set the background color in the **Format Table...** properties.

Here is the final result...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use Alerter in your report and add condition for the objects

Comment: This answer is a stub and should rather be a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), since short answers like this may be considered low quality. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to comment. If you don't have enough reputation, read [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) on how to contribute if you don't have enough reputation yet.